# How to enable toggle button and make it on if I finished typing in two edit text username and password

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I wrote a code to check if the user name and password are for admin or not ...
If yes redirect to admin activity (Activity_2) other wise redirect the user to  another activity(ac) ... 
but my code has something wrong because the status of the toggle button didn't change as I want :\

[image]

this my code for the main activity :

```
package com.example.task_7;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


    Button b1;
    ToggleButton b2;
    EditText t1,t2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        b2=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.isAdmin);
        t1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        t2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        b2.setChecked(false);
        b2.setEnabled(false);

                if(t1.getText().toString().equals("e") && t2.getText().toString().equals("123") ){

                    b2.setEnabled(true);
                    b2.setText("ON");

                } 



    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Intent i;

    if(b2.isChecked()) {

                 i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_2.class);
                 i.putExtra("UserName", t1.getText().toString());
                 i.putExtra("Password", t2.getText().toString()); 

                startActivity(i);

            }

            else {

                i  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ac.class);
                i.putExtra("UserName", t1.getText().toString());


                startActivity(i);

            }

        }
    });


  }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** You need to add `setChecked(true)` inside `afterTextChanged` or your code will never work because `b2.isChecked()` is always going to be `false`.

This is your problem: The `onCreate` function is only called when the activity is created.

When the activity is created, all texts are empty so checking if the TextViews are filled with the admin username and password does not make any sense. You must check for them each time the user presses a key. You can achieve this adding a `addTextChangedListener()` to the TextViews, so the function inside the listener is called each time the text changes:

```
b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
b2=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.isAdmin);
t1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
t2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

TextWatcher listener = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(t1.getText().toString().equals("e") && t2.getText().toString().equals("123")){
            b2.setChecked(true);
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            b2.setText("ON");
        } 
    }
};

t1.addTextChangedListener(listener);
t2.addTextChangedListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2):

You put this check in `onCreate()` method so that it is done only one time, at the beginning. You need to create `TextWatcher` for your `EditTexts`:

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s)
    {
        if(t1.getText().toString().equals("e") && t2.getText().toString().equals("123") ){
             b2.setEnabled(true);
             b2.setText("ON");
        } 
    }
});

t1.addTextChangedListener(tw);
t2.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

This way every time someone changes text in one of those `EditText`s, the condition is checked.

Of course you can think about something more efficient like creating accept button and when it is clicked, the condition is checked. But it's up to you.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll use the accept button but I'm  a beginner and I don't know about this .. for ur solution it gave may a syntax error about });

Answer (score -1):

You are checking for the admin username and password in the oncreate, which is called on creation. To check for user input of username and password put that code inside ontextchanged of edit texts.

```
if(t1.getText().toString().equals("e") && t2.getText().toString().equals("123") ){

                b2.setEnabled(true);
                b2.setText("ON");

            }
```

Comment: This will not enable the button when he has finished writting username and password, as he asks.